# Problems deploying Keycloak in HA using Postgres in Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, high-availability, keycloak

We followed the steps on this web site:

http://blog.keycloak.org/2015/04/running-keycloak-cluster-with-docker.html

and deployed keycloak with the following commands:

First, the PostgreSQL database:

```
docker run --name postgres -e POSTGRES_DATABASE=keycloak -e POSTGRES_USER=keycloak -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d postgres
```

then, we started the first instance of Keycloak:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 --name keycloak --link postgres:postgres -e POSTGRES_DATABASE=keycloak -e POSTGRES_USER=keycloak -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres
```

finally, we started the second instance of Keycloak:

```
docker run -p 8081:8080 --name keycloak2 --link postgres:postgres -e POSTGRES_DATABASE=keycloak -e POSTGRES_USER=keycloak -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -d jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres
```

When we reviewed the logs of the second instance, we saw:

```
Received new cluster view for channel keycloak: [a0cc503233bf|0] (1) [a0cc503233bf]
Received new cluster view for channel server: [a0cc503233bf|0] (1) [a0cc503233bf]
Received new cluster view for channel web: [a0cc503233bf|0] (1) [a0cc503233bf]
Received new cluster view for channel hibernate: [a0cc503233bf|0] (1) [a0cc503233bf]
Received new cluster view for channel ejb: [a0cc503233bf|0] (1) [a0cc503233bf]
```

As you can see, there's only 1 node detected.

Based on the blog, we shall see something like this (2 nodes detected):

```
Received new cluster view: [b5356f1050cc/keycloak|1] (2) [b5356f1050cc/keycloak, f25f922ce14d/keycloak]
```

---

We also looked at the **Readme** on docker hub of this image (jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres) https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak-ha-postgres/  which are the same steps that we run, but nothing seem to make Keycloak to start in HA using postgres.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/i6e/keycloak4cf/blob/master/README-more.md

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation about clustering.
The [9.4](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/server-installation-and-configuration/content/topics/clustering/multicast.html) part explains how to configure multicast.
Which is used by instances to communicate.

The private address should be changed.

According to what's done into keycloak-ha-mysql.
https://github.com/Reposoft/keycloak-ha-kubernetes/blob/keycloak-ha-mysql/server-ha-mysql/jgroups-jdbc.xsl

You can edit the standalone-ha.xml file and set the private interface value to

```
<nic xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.0" name="eth0" />
```